# Prefixing a String to an array vs Prefixing a string to an array of objects - React/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string

Why With the below declaration and assignment

```
const num = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

is this allowed and will give [1,2,3,4,5] "Jello"

```
console.log(num + "Jello");
```

But with the below declaration and assignment

```
const num = { Flavour: "Apple" };
```

This **will not** give you Apple "Jello"

```
console.log(num + "Jello");
```

Comment: Does it have something to do with the + symbol as working as a concatenator with a pure array but not an array of objects?

Comment: Please read about [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) , and [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion)

Comment: Yes, what I don't understand is that even when the objects are contained within an array for example const num = [{Flavor: Apple}, {Flavor: Mint}, {Flavor: Orange}] it still does not work. If the objects are contained within an array, shouldn't the arrays rules while utilizing the + sign take precedence and thus I should be getting the array followed by the word Jello (similar to the first example). However I am not getting that. Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: The result shown for the array example is incorrect. `num + "Jello"` results in `'1,2,3,4,5Jello'` (note the lack of brackets, or a space between the array items and "Jello").

Comment: This question could use clarification as to exactly what result is desired/expected, and how it differs from the actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: the below links to pages on MDN, which started out as the documentation for the JS in Mozilla browsers, but applies beyond that these days.)

Firstly, for `a + b` to return a sensible result, `a` and `b` should be of the same type. If they're different types, they must be [coerced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) to the same type (see also ECMAScript 2021, [section 7.1 "Type Conversion"](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-type-conversion)).

Furthermore, the [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) only works on two types: numbers and strings (see also ECMAScript 2021, [section 13.8 "Additive Operators"](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-additive-operators)). Basically, if the operands aren't both numbers, then they're coerced to strings basically by calling their `toString()` methods (the [exact process](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator) is a little more involved, and takes into account primitives, such as `null`, that don't have a `toString` method).

For arrays, [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) will call `toString()` on each element and join the results with a comma (the meat of it is defined in the specification for [Array.prototype.join](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring)). The more general [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) will, for an object literal, return simply `'[object Object]'`. This value is comes from the specification for [Object.prototype.toString](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring), and has the form `` `[object ${Tag}]` ``, where `Tag` is a string representing the builtin type of the object.

To get a string containing a representation of an object, you need to use something like [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify({ Flavour: "Apple" }) + ' Jello'
```

If you just want the values, and the object is flat (i.e. no values are themselves objects), you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
Object.values({ Cost: "Cheap", Flavour: "Apple" }) + 'Jello'
```

If you want to join the values with something other than a comma, explicitly call [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with the separator:

```
Object.values({ Cost: "Cheap", Flavour: "Apple" }).join(' ') + ' Jello'
```